# PHP access file in other directory

Tags: php, linux

I want to read a file into an array in my PHP script. I run it locally on my Linux PC. There is a file /tmp/data.txt, a copy of it in /var/www/html/tmp/data.txt and the source file is in /var/www/html/script.php.

I have tried:
`$dataArray = file('/tmp/data.txt');` but then PHP cannot open the file.

I have also tried: `$dataArray = file('tmp/data.txt');` which worked fine overall, but I would like to use the file /tmp/data.txt.

How can I access the other File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably that php isn't allowed to read the /tmp folder. It creates its own folder. You might want to google for php rights on /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

try `'./tmp/data.txt'`

`./` will imply "from current folder"

Comment: Thank you, but I wan't to access the file in /tmp/data.txt, so I need to go to the root folder.

Comment: Then you would need to use exactly `file('/tmp/data.txt');` , and the user with which the PHP script is running needs to have permissions to read this file. Do you get any specific errors?

Comment: No, but if I run `var_dump($dataArray)` there is nothing inside. I can read the file with the current user.

Comment: Without any errors I ma not sure how I can help, you can try enabling errors via `error_reporting(1);` at the beginning of the file, you can also do a test with `file_get_contents('/tmp/data.txt');` to see if the file is read and saved at least as a string, or if it is still empty

Comment: I ran both `error_reporting(1);` and `echo(file_get_contents('/tmp/data.txt'));` but there is no output.